# The link not load in the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, load

I have this code to open link in iframe and hide iframe until link is clicked then hide link after link is clicked

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#iframe1").hide();
    $("#theLink").click(function(){
        $("#iframe1").show();
        $("#linkDiv").hide();
        return false;
    });
});

</script>

<div id="linkDiv">
    <a href="http://www.example.com" id="theLink" target="iframe1">Link</a>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="#"></iframe>
```

The link not load in the iframe

Can anyone solve this problem please ?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI, `<iframe id="iframe1" name="iframe1" src="about:blank" style="display:none;"></iframe>` to avoid a FOUC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return false` cancels the default action so the link isn't followed. Take it out.